# Return OkHttp Asynchronous result has some problem

Tags: java, okhttp

I have a java `SDK`,which use `OkHttp` client(**4.0.0**) to get token from `IAM` server and return token to application.The relation may like this：Applicaiton Sync call `SDK`，`SDK` Async call `IAM`.Refer to this answer[Java - Retrieving Result from `OkHttp` Asynchronous GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308439/java-retrieving-result-from-okhttp-asynchronous-get),the code like:

The Async Class:

```
class BaseAsyncResult<T> {
private final CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

T getResult() {
    try {
        return future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

void onFailure(IOException e) {
    future.completeExceptionally(e);
}

void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
    String bodyString = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();
    future.complete(IasClientJsonUtil.json2Pojo(bodyString, new TypeReference<T>() {}));
}
}
```

Okhttp call like this:

```
public void invoke(Request request, BaseAsyncResult result) {
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                result.onFailure(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                result.onResponse(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

The application use sdk code like,iasClient is a wrapper of okhttp client :

```
 BaseAsyncResult<AuthenticationResponse> iasAsyncResult = new BaseAsyncResult();
 iasClient.invoke(request, iasAsyncResult);
 AuthenticationResponse result = iasAsyncResult.getResult();
```

The erroe message:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to x.x.x.AuthenticationResponse`

What have I missed?

Comment: One method from @Arpan Kanthal is add a private Class<T> type variable to  BaseAsyncResult and then use that class in your json2Pojo function,then the BaseAsyncResult may like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure jackson knows which class to deserialize the value to . In this case, you are asking Jackson to deserialize the response to a TypeReference , which will resolve to a Map by default unless you specify the class (in this case, AuthenticationResponse ) . The Future resolves to a linkedHashMap due to this and causes the class cast.
try replacing the below line .

```
future.complete(IasClientJsonUtil.json2Pojo(bodyString, new TypeReference<T>() {}));
```

with

```
future.complete(IasClientJsonUtil.json2Pojo(bodyString, new TypeReference<AuthenticationResponse>() {}));
```

Comment: Thank you very much,follow your method i change the code and work well.But i want `BaseAsyncResult` can support other type,can it possible?

Comment: @TongChen You can do two things. One is to pass  the type of result class in the BaseAsyncResult.Add a  private Class<T> type variable and then use that class in your json2Pojo function. Second solution is to cast the result into a map and then convert the map to pojo with the final MyPojo pojo = mapper.convertValue(map, MyPojo.class)

Answer (score 0):

One method from @Arpan Kanthal is add a private Class type variable to  BaseAsyncResult and then use that class in your json2Pojo function,then the BaseAsyncResult may like this:

```
public class BaseAsyncResult<T> {
    private final CompletableFuture<T> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    private Class<T> classType;

    public BaseAsyncResult(Class<T> classType) {
        this.classType = classType;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    void onFailure(IOException e) {
        future.completeExceptionally(e);
    }

    void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        future.complete(JacksonUtil.json2Pojo(response.body().string(), classType));
    }
}
```